# Why can't I chain .sort() after .copyOf()?

Tags: kotlin

I'll keep this very simple. Why does this work:

```
var heights = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,2,3,4)
var sortedHeights = heights.copyOf()
sortedHeights.sort()

for (i in 0..heights.size-1)
{
    println(sortedHeights[i])
}
```

But this does not?

```
var heights = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,2,3,4)
var sortedHeights = heights.copyOf().sort()

for (i in 0..heights.size-1)
{
    println(sortedHeights[i])
}
```

As you can see the only difference is the chaining with the sortedHeights array. If copyOf() returns an array, shouldn't I be able to chain it with sort()?

Comment: Because `sort()` returns `Unit` not an array.

Comment: ....Ah. I see. Thank you.

Comment: Unless you actually want to change the variables, better use `val` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

forpas answered why your code doesn't work in the comments, but you can use [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html) to allow chaining anyway:

```
var sortedHeights = heights.copyOf().apply { sort() }
```

or

```
var sortedHeights = heights.copyOf().also { it.sort() }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a builtin function performs both a `copyOf()` and a sorting: `sortedArray()`

You can change your line of code to:

```
var sortedHeights = heights.sortedArray()
```

(but you should really be using `val` instead of `var` unless you intend to change the value of the variable)